# What does the android prompt "SkipDraw reason..." mean?

Tags: android

When my app is in the foreground and I try to close and reopen the screen, my app interface looks like it's frozen.

At this point, I confirmed that any of my touch inputs actually worked, but the ui interface didn't change at all, and when I switched to another app and then switched back, the ui was refreshed, but the activity remained frozen.

Checked logcat and spit out multiple very long logs to me.

Is this a system reason? Rather than a problem with my software itself.

```
 SkipDraw reason : screen_off displaySource From updateInternalDisplay 0 state 2 caller android.view.ViewRootImpl.updateConfiguration:6269 android.app.ActivityThread.handleActivityConfigurationChanged:6888 android.app.ActivityThread.handleActivityConfigurationChanged:6775 android.app.servertransaction.ActivityConfigurationChangeItem.execute:55 android.app.servertransaction.ActivityTransactionItem.execute:45 android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks:144 android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute:101 android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage:2627 android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage:106 android.os.Looper.loopOnce:257 android.os.Looper.loop:368 android.app.ActivityThread.main:8825 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke:-2 com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run:572 com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main:1049 <bottom of call stack> <bottom of call stack> <bottom of call stack> <bottom of call stack> <bottom of call stack> <bottom of call stack> <bottom of call stack> <bottom of call stack> <bottom of call stack> <bottom of call stack> <bottom of call stack> <bottom of call stack> <bottom of call stack> <bottom of call stack> <bottom of call stack>  displayStateSource State 1 caller android.hardware.display.DisplayManagerGlobal$DisplayListenerDelegate.handleMessage:1180 android.hardware.display.DisplayManagerGlobal$DisplayListenerDelegate.lambda$sendDisplayEvent$0:1147 android.hardware.display.DisplayManagerGlobal$DisplayListenerDelegate.$r8$lambda$aO0d1U2yv7-42_0MvY8uEf7AtpE:0 android.hardware.display.DisplayManagerGlobal$DisplayListenerDelegate$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run:6 android.os.Handler.handleCallback:958 android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage:99 android.os.Looper.loopOnce:257 android.os.Looper.loop:368 android.app.ActivityThread.main:8825 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke:-2 com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run:572 com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main:1049 <bottom of call stack> <bottom of call stack> <bottom of call stack> <bottom of call stack> <bottom of call stack> <bottom of call stack> <bottom of call stack> <bottom of call stack> <bottom of call stack> <bottom of call stack> <bottom of call stack> <bottom of call stack> <bottom of call stack> <bottom of call stack> <bottom of call stack> <bottom of call stack> <bottom of call stack> <bottom of call stack>  mLastDisplayListenerState registerListeners , time 1708247929181 caller android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView:1550 android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView:426 android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView:150 android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity:5371 android.app.servertransaction.ResumeActivityItem.execute:64 android.app.servertransaction.ActivityTransactionItem.execute:45 android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState:185 android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute:103 android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage:2627 android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage:106 android.os.Looper.loopOnce:257 android.os.Looper.loop:368 android.app.ActivityThread.main:8825 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke:-2 com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run:572 com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main:1049 <bottom of call stack> <bottom of call stack> <bottom of call stack> <bottom of call stack> <bottom of call stack> <bottom of call stack> <bottom of call stack> <bottom of call stack> <bottom of call stack> <bottom of call stack> <bottom of call stack> <bottom of call stack> <bottom of call stack> <bottom of call stack>  mLastDisplayCallEvent onDisplayChanged 0 mDisplayId 0 state 1 time 1708265444321
```